# Sip.js - how to catch MediaStreamError?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, simplewebrtc, sipjs

How to catch `MediaStreamError` when it occur (e.g. when being not on `https`): [image]

I think I've tried already all `.on()` events I've found in the [Sip.js docs](https://sipjs.com/api/0.8.0/), but only `"ended"` is working when this error occurs (but I don't think this is a proper to use as a error handler) - any ideas/thoughts?

Btw. tried catching it via:

```
const simpleSip = new SIP.Web.Simple(options)
simpleSip.on('ended', function () { ... })
```

Even trying to catch it via `window.onerror` doesn't work (while e.g. [bugsnag](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/javascript/) plugin catches it properly) :| Any ideas?